# Reduce the frequency of geolocation watchPosition calls

Tags: html, gps, w3c-geolocation

I'm writing a tracking app for a logistics company, which needs to report the location of each phone back to base on a regular basis. The `geolocation.watchPosition` method seems ideal, except that as far as I can tell it updates the location as often as once per second with seemingly no way to increase the interval between callbacks. Once per second is a little too often from a data usage point of view - once per minute would be ideal.

Is there an option I can pass to watchPosition to make it execute the callback with a minimum interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could allow it to still call watchPosition once per second, but then separate out the reporting back to base into a separate callback that is run once per minute on a timer.

e.g.:

```
var GPSStore = {};
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
  function(current_location) {
    // Just store the latest co-ordinates in memory as often as they are generated
    GPSStore.location = current_location;
  }
);
// Once a minute transmit the latest co-ordinates
setInterval(function() {
  transmitLocation(GPSStore.location);
}, 1000*60);
```

Comment: For my use case I check if position has changed more than 100 meters and then update location. I do it with the `getPreciseDistance` method in `geolib`.

Answer (score 2):

PositionOptions has a property called maximumAge.

Documentation says:

> Is a positive long value indicating the maximum age in milliseconds of a possible cached position that is acceptable to return. If set to 0, it means that the device cannot use a cached position and must attempt to retrieve the real current position. If set to Infinity the device must return a cached position regardless of its age. Default: 0.
>   [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/PositionOptions)

It can help you